# l33t why is it printing three U's

Tags: java

i am having a problem i am making a l33t translator and my translator from English to l33t works for my l33t to English works other then u and what is happening is it is printing three U's i have tryed taking it out of the for loop and it will only print one but it prints it at the start of the word i have tryed putting it at the bottom out of the for and it doesnt even print one. i have also tryed `if(phrase.charAt(i) == '|') && phrase.charAt(i+1) == '_' && phrase.charAt(i+2) == '|').` here is what i got.

```
public static String translateToEnglish(String phrase) {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Hello what pharse would you like to convert in to l33t");
  phrase = scan.nextLine();
  String NewString = "";

  for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
    if (phrase.charAt(i) == '4') {
      NewString += "a";
    }

    if (phrase.charAt(i) == '8') {
      NewString += "b";
    } else {
      if (phrase.charAt(i) == '3') {
        NewString += "e";
      }
    }

    if (phrase.charAt(i) == '1') {
      NewString += "l";
    } else {
      if (phrase.charAt(i) == '0') {
        NewString += "o";
      }
    }

    if (phrase.charAt(i) == '5') {
      NewString += "s";
    } else {
      if (phrase.charAt(i) == '7') {
        NewString += "t";
      }
    }

    if (phrase.contains("|_|")) {
      NewString += "u";
    }

    if (phrase.charAt(i) == '2') {
      NewString += "z";
    }

    if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'c' || phrase.charAt(i) == 'd' || phrase.charAt(i) == 'f' || phrase.charAt(i) == 'g'
        || phrase.charAt(i) == 'h' || phrase.charAt(i) == 'i'
        || phrase.charAt(i) == 'j' || phrase.charAt(i) == 'k' || phrase.charAt(i) == 'm' || phrase.charAt(i) == 'n'
        || phrase.charAt(i) == 'p' || phrase.charAt(i) == 'q'
        || phrase.charAt(i) == 'r' || phrase.charAt(i) == 'v' || phrase.charAt(i) == 'w' || phrase.charAt(i) == 'x'
        || phrase.charAt(i) == 'y') {
      NewString += phrase.charAt(i);
    }
    // if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'c') {
  }

  System.out.println(NewString);
  return phrase;
}
```

Comment: I didn't really read all that but...have you tried debugging? It seems like you have some unexpected behaviour, which will be easy to identify and fix by printing some variables or stepping through your code.

Comment: Yeah the way it is not it just goes through the loop 3 times then adds three u but when i have the phrase.chatAt(i) && ... then it runs through gets the u but does not increase the count so it crashes

Comment: You don't need us to find out why. Print some variables and compare the printed values to the expected values.

Comment: My suggestion: Remake the entire thing, this seems horribly structured. Logically think about what you plan on writing before you actually write it. Perhaps you could write some pseudo code first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement for `|_|` is doing a `String#contains` comparison and is not elsed. So for every iteration in the loop it will print a u if the phrase contains this sequence of characters.

If you use your alternative of checking each char at i, i+1, i+2 you will firstly have to make sure that your phrase is long enough and then if it is true, in that if statement you will have to make sure you increment i by 3 i.e

```
if(phrase.length() < i+2 
   && phrase.charAt(i) == '|') 
   && phrase.charAt(i+1) == '_' 
   && phrase.charAt(i+2) == '|')
{
    NewString += "u";
    i += 2;  // Will get the third increment from loop
    continue;
}
```

Also if you make sure the structure is always `if..if else...else`, the final check where is just replaces with the same character can just be reduced to an else without needing to or together every other character

Answer (score 2):

For every char in the word you check if it contains a "u". It will always be true because you don't check at a specific position of the word. You would have to check for a | followed by _ followed by | and then add a "u" instead of generally checking if it's somewhere in the input.